# Store object/array in jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

How can I store an object/array in JavaScript Cookies?
I tried that simple code

```
var item = { 
    price: 200,   
    company: 'Microsoft',   
    quantity: 500,
    code: 'm33'
}

console.log(item);
Cookies.set('item', item);
console.log(Cookies.get('item'));
```

It shows all the values in the first console message, but gives only "[object Object]" in the second. Looks like js-cookie cannot work with objects correctly. Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Could [de]serialize it. `Cookie.set('item', JSON.stringify(item))` / `JSON.parse(Cookie.get('item'))`

Answer (score 1):

You are storing an object, and cookies are allowed text-only. Remember that cookies have a max-length of 4 KB, so you can't store a lot of information here (use `localStorage` instead).

To solve this problem, you must to stringify the json first:

```
Cookies.set('item', JSON.stringify(item));
```

And you'll store a stringified object. To access it then, you must to parse the string:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(Cookie.get('item')));
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have been looking for it for the last 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Cookies.getJSON('item')
```

js-cookie has built-in support for JSON parsing as from version 2.0.0, there is no need to change how you set it. For more information, see https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.1.0#json

Answer (score -1):

In cookie you can only store string. So in order to store object first you convert your object into string. Using [this plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) here is an example:

```
var people = [
    {"id": 123, "name": "Mazahir Eyvazli"},
    {"id": 128, "name": "Mayki Nayki"},
    {"id": 131, "name": "Mike Shinoda"}
];
$.cookie("people", JSON.stringify(people));
```

If you want to access your *people* as an object from cookie

```
// $.cookie("people") will return people object as an string
// therefore we parse it to JSON object
var people = $.parseJSON($.cookie("people"));
// now we can access our object
people[0]["id"] // --> 123
people[1]["name"] // --> Mayki Nayki
```

Comment: OP is already using a cookie library. Switching to another one won't make any difference